# Is there a way to return different keySelectors to one OrderBy?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a long line with an `OrderBy` inside. This line repeats itself several times with only a minor difference:

```
OrderBy(m => m.Name)
OrderBy(m => m.CreationTime)
```

etc.

In the interest of maintainability, is there a way to make only one line, and have it call some method, or perhaps use some `Action` that will take care of returning the correct field? The problem is that the fields are not of the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this comes closer to what you want

```
public IComparable GetKey(int keyNum)
{
    switch (keyNum) {
        case 1:
            return Name;
        case 2:
            return CreationTime;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Sorting would occur like this

```
.OrderBy(m => m.GetKey(1))
```

---

Yet another way is to return a delegate

```
public static Func<MyClass, IComparable> GetKeySelector(int keyNum)
{
    switch (keyNum) {
        case 1:
            return m => m.Name;
        case 2:
            return m => m.CreationTime;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}

.OrderBy(MyClass.GetKeySelector(1));
```

Comment: +1 Thanks. I tried your first suggestion but I can't seem to get it to work. (See edit to the question.) Do you know why?

Comment: OK. I got VS to accept it with: `GetKey(f,1)`. I know just have to check that it works.

Comment: Works great. Thank you very much for your time! Deserves more than one upvote.

Comment: My `GetKey` is a method in `MyClass`, therefore I did not need the first parameter.Note that my second solution does not need this parameter, since no concrete instance is required to build the delegate.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this method signature:

> public static IOrderedEnumerable OrderBy(
>       this IEnumerable source,
>       Func keySelector,
>       IComparer comparer
>   )

You need to give it `IComparer<TKey>`

```
data.OrderBy(x => x, new FooComparer());
data.OrderBy(x => x, new BarComparer());
data.OrderBy(x => x, new BazComparer());
```

Not sure if it's much cleaner to create classes just for sorting...

You can also create different methods that sort the list according to an enum they get as a parameter,
I think it's a lot cleaner solution.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx)

Comment: @ispiro. You can also create different methods that sort the list according to an enum they get as a parameter, it looks like a nicer solution.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually what I'm trying to do, but have only the IComparer prepared in that method.

Comment: @ispiro. Each method would sort the list hard coded (once). And then use the methods to sort the lists for you.

Comment: Sorry, lost you there. So far I have: `delegate string FieldInfoToString(FieldInfo f);` `IComparer<FieldInfo> ic = new FieldInfoToString();` am I going in the right direction? How do I create the `FooComparer` you mentioned?

Comment: @ispiro. I believe that kind of full abstraction is impossible or extremely difficult.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are copying the same entire selection multiple times?  You would just need this:

```
.OrderBy(m=>m.Name)
.ThenBy(m=>m.CreationTime);
```

Comment: It is `Name` **or** `CreationTime`

Comment: Thanks. But no, the lines are in separate methods, either one is called or the other. And I want to make only one method which than calls a second method that returns a "key" to the first.

Answer (score 0):

After `OrderBy` you must use `ThenBy`

```
.OrderBy(m => m.Name)
.ThenBy(m => m.CreationTime)
```

But this does not answer your question. Implement `IComparable<Type_of_m>` in the type of `m`, then you can compare with

```
.OrderBy(m => m)
```

---

```
class Type_of_m : IComparable<Type_of_m>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Type_of_m other)
    {
        int comp = Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
        if (comp != 0) {
            return comp;
        }
        return CreationTime.CompareTo(other.CreationTime);
    }
}
```

---

If you want to be able to order the items in several ways, then use a Comparer as gdoron
explained. This is a good case for nested classes.

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public static readonly IComparer<MyClass> NameComparer = new MyNameComparaer();
    private class MyNameComparaer : IComparer<MyClass>
    {
        public int Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y)
        {
            return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
        }
    }

    public static readonly IComparer<MyClass> DateComparer = new MyDateComparer();
    private class MyDateComparer : IComparer<MyClass>
    {
        public int Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y)
        {
            return x.CreationTime.CompareTo(y.CreationTime);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then order like this

```
.OrderBy(m => m, MyClass.NameComparer)
```

or like this

```
.OrderBy(m => m, MyClass.DateComparer)
```

Comment: It is `Name` **or** `CreationTime`

Comment: Thanks. But no, the lines are in separate methods, either one is called or the other. And I want to make only one method which than calls a second method that returns a "key" to the first.